# How do I use JSON Stringify to replace all keys and values?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, recursion

I'm working on a way that takes advantage of the replacer function argument in JSON.Stringify in JavaScript in order to change the word-case (toUpper /toLower case), the problem is my JSON is not straight key:value, some values are keys also and they have values themselves, so I need to go through all keys and values, check if the value is also a key and make sure I change the case (toUpper or toLower) for all keys and values.
I know that the replacer function in JSON.Stringify(object,ReplacerFunction) iterates through all keys and values and makes the modifications inside then return keys and values, but although I've been reading about this for a wWhile I can't apply it, and I am not sure if I should apply recursion inside the replacer function or how, any help is appreciated.

Code I had:

```
 function _replacer(name,val){
   if(typeof val != "object"){
       return val.toString().toUpperCase()
   }
   if(typeof name != "object"){
            return name.toString().toUpperCase()
        }

   console.log("key = "+name+" type: "+typeof  name);
   console.log("value ="+val+" type: "+typeof  val);

    }
```

Also:

```
 function _replacer(name,val){
   if(typeof val != "object" &&typeof  val ==="string"){
       return val=val.toUpperCase()
   }
   if(typeof name != "object" &&typeof  name ==="string"){
            name=name.toUpperCase()
        }
    return val;
    }
```

Also , i eventually got to this stage :

```
 var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j, function(key, value) {
        return typeof value === "string" ? value.toUpperCase() : value
    }));
```

but this code only capitalizes the very lower level values, not all the keys/values, the reason is because i can only return one value from the replacer function, which is in this case the value.

Comment: Share the code you've tried.

Comment: @jmargolisvt , shared.

Comment: it's amazes me how much people are more inclined to down-vote my reasonable question rather than say something useful.

Comment: In Javascript of a key cannot be an object. For any key `k` you add to an object, `k.toString()` is called. Verify with `var key = { toString() { return "test" } }; var obj = { [key]: key }; JSON.stringify(obj) === '{"test":{}}'`.

Comment: The problem is that questions without code are generally unanswerable, so folks downvote it so others don't waste time on a poorly-asked question.  It's good to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you're new here.

Comment: I'm confused by this part:  `some values are keys also and they have values themselves, so I need to go through all keys and values`.  All json keys correlate to some value.  a "value" is not a "key".  Now that value may be of a different data type (ie, array vs object vs string).  Are you just trying to do a deep traversal of the entire json object, uppercasing anything that is a string type?

Comment: yes thatys the idea, however i am not sure if recursion is needed here, and if i is needed, then how do  i do it inside the function (replacer)

Answer (score 0):

The `replacer` function in `JSON.stringify`, does not allow you to replace keys, as [documented in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). It allows you to transform values, or to omit key/value pairs altogether (by returning `undefined`).

Your best bet is probably to transform the object before stringifying it. Underscore or Lodash would make this pretty easy, but you can do it natively without too much trouble like this:

```
const xform = obj => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((xformed, key) => {
    let value = obj[key]

    if (typeof value ==='string') value = value.toUpperCase()
    else if (typeof value === 'object') value = xform(value)

    xformed[key.toUpperCase()] = value
    return xformed
  }, {})
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(xform({a: 'b', c: 1, d: {e: 'f'}})))
// {"A":"B","C":1,"D":{"E":"F"}}
```

You could also use RegEx and `replace` *after* it is stringified if you are so inclined. The code is certainly shorter, but perhaps less readable:

```
const stringified = JSON.stringify({a: 'b', c: 1, d: {e: 'f'}})
console.log(stringified.replace(/".+?"/g, s => s.toUpperCase()))
// {"A":"B","C":1,"D":{"E":"F"}}
```

Comment: It's an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). `s => s` is roughly equivalent to `function(s) { return s }`.

They are both functions which take a single parameter (`s`) and then return it (or return it uppercased in my answer). The differences are somewhat technical, primarily that arrow functions do not have `this` or `arguments` objects.